# How can I reverse my array list in foreach?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I reverse the list item in this looping, I wan to let the latest entry display on the top first.

```
List {
                    ForEach(self.entryController.moods, id: \.id)
                    { mood in
                        HStack{
                            VStack {
                                Text(mood.monthString)
                                    .font(.title2)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .foregroundColor(mood.emotion.moodColor)
                                Text("\(mood.dayAsInt)")
                                    .font(.title2)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .foregroundColor(mood.emotion.moodColor)
                                
                            }
                            
                            RowView(mood: mood)
                        }
                        
                    }.onDelete { (index) in
                        self.entryController.deleteMood(at: index)
                        
                    }
                }.refreshable {
                    await entryController.loadStats()}
```

I tried to use .reverse() function but It seems like can't work. Any solution on this?

Comment: Sort the array first before using it.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of pairs of functions in the standard library that have a mutating version and a non-mutating version - they are named like `sort` and `sorted`, and `reverse` and `reversed`.  You need the non-mutating reversed method.

But really, this work should be in a *view model*, not in the view, so that moods, is maintained in the right order ready for the view

Comment: As Shadowrun says, use `reversed()`, not `reverse`. That would give you a ForEach line of `ForEach(self.entryController.moods.reversed(), id: \.id)`. But also as ShadowRun says, you should reverse the order of your data in your *view model*, not in the view. (Voted)

Answer (score 1):

The solution you are looking for is probably the following:

```
List {
    ForEach(self.entryController.moods.reversed(), id: \.id)
    { mood in
        HStack{
            VStack {
                Text(mood.monthString)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(mood.emotion.moodColor)
                Text("\(mood.dayAsInt)")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(mood.emotion.moodColor)
                
            }
            
            RowView(mood: mood)
        }
        
    }.onDelete { (index) in
        self.entryController.deleteMood(at: index)
        
    }
}.refreshable {
    await entryController.loadStats()
}
```

⚠️ **Nevertheless I would handle the order of your data - as already mentioned by Shadowrun - in the view model**

Comment: Thx its work... yes I tried to put it in my controller, im not using mvvm